# partition resizing and backups

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, backup

Here is my situation.  I have dual-boot on my macbook with Ubuntu/OSX.  ~30gb partition for Ubuntu and the rest for OSX on a 256gb SSD.  When I first started with Linux I didn't know much at all, and just followed on online guide for dual-boot which said that 20gb is fine, so I went with a little more at 30gb.  But now since I want to keep running Linux I want some more space for the Linux partition.  What I want to do is resize the two partitions, take some from Mac partition and give to Linux partition.  I would love to be able to do this without having to wipe data.  Is this at all possible, maybe with something like gparted?  Of course with this kind of task things can go wrong so of course I want to backup my system.  What is the best way to back up my entire Ubuntu partition as is?  DD, tar, clonezilla?  And after once I have the partitions resized how do I restore?  Would it restore with the partition size the same?  Also, I do realize this is not a Mac forum but what is a good way to back up my Mac partition, would the above mentioned methods work for Mac as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To modify your partition sizes, use `GPARTED`. However, it should be used from a "Live CD" since the partitions to be modified must be `unmounted`.

Before doing anything, back-up your entire hard drive to an **external** device, such as a USB hard drive. There are numerous Linux based back-up programs for doing this, I do not have any specific recommendations.

In terms of backing-up the MAC partitions, test the Linux program that you wish to use to verify that it will do this. If not (a potential solution) create a MAC folder in your Linux partition and copy all the files you want backed-up from the MAC partition into that Linux folder.

Furthermore, if the backup program does not work for the MAC partition, you may wish to create a shell script that copies the MAC files into the Linux partition on a periodic basis. Again backup files should be stored on an external device.